# Docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized, after login in success

Tags: android, docker

Hi I am working on `battery-historian` to get battery history of android app, I have installed and login in Docker success in Android studio terminal, and when I run `docker run -p 5555:9999 gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable:3.0 --port 9999`
 , there always display a message showing the option is unauthorized:

```
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable:3.0' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credent
ials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication Does not help?

Comment: @cricket_007, Is there any way that I don't need to install Go? Since I already Login success, why am I still get the error? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. I'm just pointing out that link in the error probably addresses your problems.

Comment: "in one of three ways" ... two of those are not using Go

Comment: @cricket_007, Hi I have checked that link and used login method it provided, and it still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. Also found it mentioned in a comment (Dec 13 2017, 23 upvotes as of now) on https://github.com/google/battery-historian/issues/125.

No response from Google it seeems, but using https://hub.docker.com/r/bhaavan/battery-historian/ as a workaround has been suggested, which seems to work for me too.